# Add sound to animation played every few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this bell below that is been animation every few second.

demo
http://inspectelement.com/demos/css3/bell

the code
http://inspectelement.com/tutorials/ring-a-bell-with-css-keyframe-animations

I want to add a sound bell that I have and I want the sound to be played only when the animation start every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var soundFile = 'sound.wav';
playSound(soundFile);
setInterval(function () {
    playSound(soundFile);
}, 8000);

function playSound(audio) {
    var soundElement = '<audio style="display:none; width: 0px; height: 0px;" id="audioNotifier" src="' + audio + '" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>';
    $('#audioContainer').html(soundElement);
    $('#audioNotifier')[0].play();
}
```

Firstly there's a timeout. Each 8 seconds the `playSound` function is being invoked.
`playSound` sets HTML5 audio player in the audio container and plays the audio. The audio container is only a DOM element, nothing special. The url to your sound file should be passed as argument to `playSound`.

Comment: ok,it's working,the only issue is the the first time the sound play is after 8 second,and I need the sound to be played when the page is loaded,and of course every 8 seconds.

Comment: You don't need to pass the url to the sound file as argument of `playSound`. Now you just have to set it as value of `soundFile` variable.